# Variable scope in __init__ method?

Tags: python, class, oop, scope

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age
        self.ageGroup = ageGroup


    def findAgeGroup(self):
        if age >= 80:
            ageGroup= "old"
            print ageGroup

John= Person(95)
John.findAgeGroup
```

So my Question is probably a pretty simple one. In the above code in the `__init__` method the variable `self.age` is set when a new instance of the `Person` class is instantiated? And all of the other variables in the `__init__` method are put there because they are related to self.age? For example in the `findAgeGroup` method `age` is used to derive a value for `ageGroup.` So would the only time you list `self.ageGroup` in the `__init__` method be if you plan to derive the value from `self.age` which is called in when a new instance of the class is created?

Comment: You need to use `if self.age >= 80:` (and `self.ageGroup = "old"`, etc).

Comment: 1. It sounds like you need to keep reviewing a Python OOP tutorial. 2. This code would produce a `NameError`.

Comment: also note that in `self.ageGroup = ageGroup` ageGroup in undefined
and in `John.findAgeGroup` you probably mean `John.findAgeGroup()`

Comment: @Nullman i think you just answered my question. So `self.ageGroup` shouldn't be in the `__init__` method at all? Because it's not defined when a new instance of `person` is created?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a tutorial service.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I tried to delete but it has already been answered so it won't allow me to.

Comment: @CodyPace yes. what you CAN do is define it between the class and the __init__ like this:
`class Person(object):
    ageGroup = 'string goes here'
    def __init__(self, age):`
that way you can access `self.ageGroup` inside init

Comment: @CodyPace do NOT edit the solution that is provided to you in your question. It invalidates answers. In this case, just accept the answer provided to mark that your question is solved, and let everyone move on. Thanks.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier the code i posted was not code i was actually trying to run but rather an example to illustrate my question about scope. My question was whether `self.ageGroup` actually belonged in the `__init__` method. I had seen several examples of code that had added variables in the `__init__` method that were not set when a new instance of the class was created and was confused to why they initialized those variables there instead of somewhere else in the program. I edited the code because the answers where correcting the code instead of answering my question about scope.

Comment: Also to everyone... I attempted to delete this post because i didn't convey my question properly. I should have tested the code first and it caused confusion. I would really like for this post to be deleted because it isn't going help anyone including me.

Comment: @CodyPace Well, that is an unfortunate turn of events. Deleting the post will leave a bad trace on your account, as there is an upvoted answer on it. I should have been more cautious, and you could have thought to post the exact code you run, but I think at this point we can only let it go, and stop thinking about it. For correctness sake, you should write an answer (you can totally do that on your own post) with what Nullman said that solved your problem, and accept it, since it really *was* the problem, and not the `age.` prefix

Comment: Been three years since this post published and it's blocking me from asking anymore questions. From what I can tell there's no way to rectify this 6 year old mistake as editing the question will take away from answers, and deleting the post will also do that? Any solutions here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python you actually always need the `self` to reference instance variables unlike e.g. Java's `this`:

```
def findAgeGroup(self):
    if self.age >= 80:
        self.ageGroup = "old"
        print self.ageGroup 
   # also Python prefers snake_case: self.age_group
```